# Conditional probability of two continuous random variables

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability

"EDIT:
Changed my $k'=k$ to $k'=1$, hope the question does not change alot, due to comments"

I have:
$X$~$U[0,1]$, as $k$ is just a number, could be $1,2,3$ or even a million.
$Y$~$U[0,X]$
$Z$~$U[0,Y]$
I have to find $f_{\left(Z|Y,X\right)},f_{\left(Y|X\right)},f_{\left(Z|X\right)}$
Problem it, I really do not know how to start finding them.
To find $f_{\left(Y|X\right)}$, I thought of maybe finding $f_{\left(X,Y\right)}$ will make me be able to find it, but I still have to find $f_Y$ afterwards and its also problematic ( And I do not really know how to find $f_{\left(X,Y\right)}$ also, sadly.
since $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent on random variable, I do not know how to look at it.
Any help will be welcomed, how to see a uniform random variable that depend on another random variable.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for $f_{Z\mid Y, Z}$ rather than one of those $Z$ being an $X$ ?  But if so, then which one?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad!! I mean $X$ at the end!! Sorry!! will edit!!

Comment: The above is absurd. If $Z$ only depends on $Y$, $(Y,Z)$ does not depend on $X$ and therefore $Y$ would not depend on $X$.

Comment: @Speltzu  No, $Z$ depends on $Y$ *and*  $Y$ on $X$, so $Z$ does depend on $X$ through that.

Comment: @BenShaines  Note: if you are given the value of $Y$, then also giving the value of $X$ adds no further information about the probability distribution for $Z$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp what do you mean by that? ( last sentence )
when you say value of Y not giving any information for Z, its because $Z$ only depends on $Y$  right? because its distribution PDF function is only dependent on the argument of $Y$, and thanks for the help ( edited here since I know it is not allowed to write comment just for thanks )

Comment: No.   $Z$ depends on $Y$, which depends on $X$, so $Z$ does depend on $X$.   But $Z$ and $X$ are *conditionally independent* when given $Y$.

Comment: The above is impossible. There is no distribution $(X,Y,Z)$ that can satisfy the conditions of the statement.

Comment: @Speltzu Why? if $k=1$ or $k=2$, is it any different? At my question I had with $k=1$, but another question was with $k=2$, so I wrote $k$ because I did not think it was harmfull, if it is harmfull, I will edit my question now to $k=1$

Comment: @GrahamKemp So you mean $(Z|Y)$ and $(X|Y)$ are independent? sorry, my english is not that best

Comment: Also, Edited original post, hope its not affecting bad the question. I wrote the exact question, just thought that if I put $k'=k$ it will not be any different from $k'=1$ just with scalar added.

Comment: @Ben Shaines It is not possible that simultaneously $(Y,Z)$ does not depend on $X$ and $Y$ does.

Comment: Sorry, I take back what I said. I had misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for making sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent on random variable, I do not know how to look at it.

Exactly. $~Y\sim\mathcal U[1, X]$ , which is more properly written as $(Y\mid X)\sim\mathcal U[0,X]$, means that $Y$ is uniformly distributed dependent on the value given for $X$.  Thus it is telling you exactly that the conditional probability density function is:

$$f_{\small (Y\mid X)}(y\mid x) = (1/x)\,\mathbf 1_{y\in[0,x]}$$

Likewise you have $f_{\small(Z\mid Y)}(z\mid y)$ so you may use this to find  $f_{\small(Z\mid X)}(z\mid x)$ .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be $f(x,y,z)=1/xy\quad 0\leq z\leq y\leq x\leq 1$, in that case:
\begin{gather*}
f(x,y)=\int_0^y\frac{1}{xy}dz=\frac{1}{x},\quad f(x,z)=\int_z^x\frac{1}{xy}dy=\frac{1}{x}ln\frac{x}{z},\quad f(y,z)=\int_y^1\frac{1}{xy}dx=\frac{1}{y}ln\frac{1}{y}\\
f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{x}dy=1,\quad f(y)=\int_y^1\frac{1}{x}dx=ln\frac{1}{y},\quad f(z)=\int_z^1\frac{1}{y}ln\frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{1}{2}ln^2\frac{1}{z}
\end{gather*}
From where:
\begin{gather*}
f_{Y/X}(x,y)=\frac{1}{x},\quad f_{Z/X}(x,z)=\frac{1}{x}ln\frac{x}{z},\quad f_{Z/Y}(y,z)=\frac{1}{y},\quad f_{Z/X,Y}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{y}
\end{gather*}
But there could be other solutions where $f_{Z/X}$ and $f_{Z/X,Y}$ were different.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Would have up-voted it if I could, but maybe next post when Ill have 15 I will upvote :)
Understood good :)